# Novel about 2 Teleporting Spies Chasing Each Other Throughout the Galaxy

Tags: story-identification, novel, teleportation

I'm looking for the title & author of a novel that I read in the 1970's.  It's about a government spy who can teleport chasing a rebel telepathic spy who can also teleport throughout the galaxy.  It's a cat and mouse novel with a very clever twist at the end.  The book had a yellow cover if I remember correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: What was the 'clever twist'?

Comment: Titke says "spies chasing each other" but body of question only says government spy is chasing rebel spy. Please resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: Teleporting spy, cat and mouse game and clever twist, in a novel in that timeframe make me think of "The Programmed Man" by Jean and Jeff Sutton (1968), but only one of the spies there is a teleporter and telepathy is alluded to, but not relevant to the story. Might still be worth checking out.

Comment: Might this novel be Cluster #1 by Piers Anthony? The plot has a human colonist from a very primitive planet sent on a mission with his kirlian soul transferred to alien bodies on other planets, in pursuit of a nemesis.

Comment: This does sound like The Programmed Man.
The ‘Federation exiles people as soon as they are known to have psychic powers; inevitably they rebel.

The federal agent tries to discover whether the wreck of a warship was accident or sabotage, and whether its weapons have been stolen.
The rebel agent (capable of teleportation) is being hunted across Earth.

Surprise ending: the ‘federal agent is the rebel agent; the real federal agent had been captured by telepaths, brainwashed into believing he was the rebel agent. 
Juvenile science fiction, but good of its kind.

Comment: The Programmed Man has a mostly yellow cover.

Comment: Thank you all for responding.  I think the novel, "The Programmed Man" by Jeff and Jean Sutton, may be it based on the comments said here and on Amazon.com.  I'm going to buy it and read it to see if it the same book that I have been searching for so many years.

Comment: Valorum, if you are not planning to read the book, then I can tell you of the clever twist.  Is it possible for you to message me privately since I don't want to spoil it for others who may want to read the novel.  Thanks.